# How to dynamically enable wire logging for Apache Http Client in Java

Tags: apache, http, httpclient

The usual way to enable wire logging is to put http.wire entry in logback xml . Is there a dynamic way to toggle this feature ? Dynamic ,  meaning -like a hot swap, without a server re-start .

Answer (score 1):

After researching enough , it appears like - it can be controlled only through logback xml ,and definitely with a server reboot .

Entry Needed  in logback.xml(as below) :

```
<logger name="org.apache.http.wire" level="DEBUG">
```

P.S :

Please note that , the library/dependency that i am referring here is apache http one as below .

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
<artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
<version>SomeVersion</version>
</dependency>
```